# Appending a ListBox list in AHK

Tags: user-interface, listbox, autohotkey

I have a text file with "usernames" on it:

```
; info.txt
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

What I want to do is create a ListBox with all the users I have in that file. My first thought was this:

```
Gui, Add, Button, , Log in
getUsers()
Gui, Show

getUsers()
{
    loop
    {
        FileReadLine, line, info.txt, %A_Index%
        if ErrorLevel
            Break
        Gui, Add, ListBox, cBlue, %line%
    }
}
```

But then instead of getting this:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2oyg.png)

I got this:
[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNQYR.png)

Which makes complete sense, but how can I do this correctly? I couldn't find any sort of append option for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, but the choices aren't added with one line each. Instead, you'll have to state a

> a pipe-delimited list

(see [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#ListBox))

So your function will instead concatenate a string and then add it to the gui once:

```
getUsers()
{
    choices := "" ; if you leave this line out, it'll work too I guess, but you might get a warning if #warn was set so
    loop
    {
        FileReadLine, line, info.txt, %A_Index%
        if ErrorLevel
            Break
        choices .= line "|"
    }
    Gui, Add, ListBox, cBlue, %choices%
}
```

Comment: I tested it, 100% works, but I have a couple questions. This is probably as easy answer, but why don't have to put "line," in the last line of the loop in %'s? Also, shouldn't there be a "." between line and "|" to connect them?

Comment: @ProfessorMilk Yes this topic is very confusing at first. There are two equal operators, `=` and `:=` which work differently. See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm @ "Storing values in variables". `.=`, `+=` etc work like the colon-equal operator `:=` and thus, you don't need `%`s here.

Comment: Concerning your second question: Yes, a `.` wouldn't be too wrong there, but since some AHK version, the dots can be omitted.

Comment: Just to clairify: `choices .= line . "|"` would be 100% the same like `choices = %choices%%line%|`

Comment: Ahh okay, so you can put the `.` between everything, or just put them next to each other and it works the same way?

Comment: @ProfessorMilk yeah but you'll need at least one whitespace character inbetween, I think. Not sure. Note that with the `=` equal operator, a dot `.` will just be a literal string dot, as a `"."`  is with the `:=` operator.